# Why won't the cells in my table view display any text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've been working through an online tutorial about creating a To Do list app for iOS, but it's come to my attention that the tutorial uses an outdated version of Swift (link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1).  I tried to correct the code according to the new standards, but when I build and run the app it only displays an empty table: no text is visible.

I pasted my code below.  It includes a couple of print statements that I used for debugging, but only the first one ("hello world") appears to run.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var toDoItems = [ToDoItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "First text"))
    print("hello world")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    //self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    if toDoItems.count > 0 {
        return
    }

    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 1"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 2"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 3"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 4"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 5"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 6"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 7"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 8"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 9"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 10"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 11"))
    toDoItems.append(ToDoItem(text: "text 12"))

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toDoItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    print("should assign text here")
    let item = toDoItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = item.text
    return cell
 }
}
```

Comment: Try `tableView.reloadData()` after appending the toDoItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of this line in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView = UITableView()
```

The `tableView` `@IBOutlet` should be connected in your *Storyboard*.  By assigning `UITableView()` you are creating a second `UITableView` which isn't the one that is on screen.

---

To connect the `tableView` outlet in the *Storyboard*, click on the circle to the left of the outlet and drag to the tableView in the ViewController:

[image: Hooking up the tableView IBOutlet]

Comment: thank you- much appreciated!  I followed your suggestions and now my app is running smoothly.